# How to block ip Ranges using http modules?

Tags: c#, ip, range, httpmodule

How to block Ip ranges using http modules with c# . I have a simple solution but its for single Ip and How can I read IPs from  xml file in http modules so that if an IP is there in that file it will be blocked  .Here is my code

```
public class MyHandler :IHttpModule
{
 public MyHandler(){}

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);
    }
    private void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = (source as HttpApplication).Context;
        List<string> BlackListIp = new List<string>();
        BlackListIp.Add("127.0.0.1");

        if (BlackListIp.Contains(context.Request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            context.Response.Write("<h1 style='color:red;'>Your IP is Blocked</h1>");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that you already have the code to block IPs.  Is your question how do you read from an xml file from within an http module?

Comment: Yes it is , i have the code @JohnW

Answer (score 0):

Just add the xml file inside app_data folder and read it using XDocument.
You can event use Cache with FileDependency to improve performance.